# Sorting out list with several properties

Tags: c#, list, visual-studio-2008, sorting, .net-2.0

I am pretty confused with sorting out list in C#, I have gone through different tutorials for sorting e.g. sorting using list (sort method) or use IComparable but nothing actually helped me with what I want.

for example I have a list of cars,

```
Car Number

Car Title

and few other properties
```

Now Car number can be any double number or it can be Nan (null) and Car Title can never be null.

I want to sort list in a way that first it gets sorted by Car Numbers and if they are not available for a car then use its title to sort rest of cars.

so if I have something like this,

```
Car 1      100.0 (car number)                  BMW x6 (car name)
Car 2      (there isn't any car number)        Mercedies A class (car name)
Car 3      99.0                                Alpha Romeo
Car 4      1.2                                 Jeep
Car 5      4.1                                 Victoria Marshall 1933
Car 6      no number                           Vauxhal
```

Out put I want my list class to be sorted as

```
Car 4, Car 5, Car 3, Car 1, Car 2, Car 6
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: I created a class with properties and not sure what to do after that to sort it out, if I use ICompareable it will only sort out car Numbers not rest of them

Comment: -1 vote seems a little harsh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like

```
var lst = new List<Cars>()

//add cars to list

lst = lst.Orderby(c => c.CarNumber).ToList();
```

you can extend it like this:

```
lst = lst.Orderby(c => c.CarNumber).ThenBy(c=> c.Title).ToList();
```

Or

You implement the IComparable so it will sort the way you want:

```
public class Car : IComparable<Car> 
{ 
    public string Number { get; set; } 

    public int CompareTo(Car obj) 
    { 
        return obj.Number.CompareTo(Number); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: No, LINQ available since C# 3.0, but you mentioned .net 3.5 in your tags.

Comment: you could implement IComparable on the car class, and then the `Sort()` method on list should work

Comment: yes but it will only sort out by car number not alphabetics order

Comment: that depends on your implementation af IComparable:
 `public class Car : IComparable<Car>
  {
    public string Number { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(Car obj)
    {
      return obj.Number.CompareTo(Number);
    }
  }`

Comment: ah I see, thats what I was looking for, if you can add it to your answer I will accept it :)